# making an <i> tag the value of a <input type='button'>

Tags: html

I am using [Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), and would like to make the value of a simple `<input type='button'>` one of the fa icons e.g. `<i class='fa fa-bold'></i>`

However, when I write:

```
<input id='bold' type='button'><i class='fa fa-bold'></i></input>
```

it renders a button and then, to the right of that, the Font Awesome icon. 
Is this not something feasible to achieve?

Comment: what is wrong with `<button><i class='fa fa-bold'></i></button>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the button tag instead? and then put the

```
<i class='fa fa-bold'></i>
```

inside the button tag, like

```
<button id="bold"><i class='fa fa-bold'></i></button>
```

I believe input elements are void elements therefore they have no content. You can achieve it through css if you insist tho'.

Answer (score 3):

[`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) elements are [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements):

> Void elements: `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`,
>   `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track`, `wbr`

Therefore, they have no content:

> [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) can't have any contents (since there's no end tag, no
>   content can be put between the start tag and the end tag).

You can only display text in them via the [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute [[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-input-element-as-a-button)]:

> When the *input-button* binding applies to an [`input`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) element
>   whose [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-type) attribute is in the [...] [Button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#button-state-(type=button)) state, the
>   element is expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a
>   button, about one line high, containing the contents of the element's
>   [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) attribute

If you want to render HTML elements inside a button, use [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) elements instead [[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-button-element-0)]:

> When the *button* binding applies to a [`button`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) element, the
>   element is expected to render as an 'inline-block' box rendered as a
>   button whose contents are the contents of the element.